# Inserting into Tables without creating duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following 5 tables:

### tblCustomer

```
CustomerID   CustomerName   
 -------     ------------
   1         ABC Bank     
   2         Chase Bank
```

### tblOrderType

```
OrderTypeID    OrderTypeName   
 ----------    ------------
   1           Assignment     
   2           LienRelease
   3           Document Retrieval
```

### tblActivity

```
ActivityID        ActivityName   
 ----------       ------------
   1              Received     
   2              Keyed
   3              Printed
   4              Delivered To Customer
```

### tblOrder

```
OrderID        CustomerID      OrderTypeID   LoanNumber
 ----------    ------------    -----------   ----------
   1           1                1            45584565
   2           1                1            45566856
   3           1                1            45565584
   4           1                1            45588545
```

### tblOrderActivity

```
OrderID        ActivityID    ActivityDate
 ----------    -----------   ----------
   1           1             2007-04-16 8:34:00 AM
   1           2             2007-04-16 9:22:00 AM  
   1           3             2007-04-16 9:51:00 AM 
   1           4             2007-04-16 4:14:00 PM  
   2           1             2007-04-16 8:34:00 AM
   2           3             2014-12-16 10:33:09 AM
   3           1             2007-04-16 8:34:00 AM
   3           2             2007-04-16 9:22:00 AM
   3           3             2007-04-16 9:51:00 AM
   3           4             2007-04-16 4:14:00 PM
   4           1             2007-04-16 8:34:00 AM
   4           2             2007-04-16 9:22:00 AM
   4           3             2007-04-16 9:51:00 AM
```

The information has been changed for protection purposes. So say I need to be able to create new Document Retrieval orders for every Assignment order Since new Assignment orders can be added every day, I need to be sure that the query can be run at any time without creating duplicate entries. Each new order also has to have a received activity under the tblOrderActivity table with the Current Date/Time. I am at a complete loss and was hoping you could help me.

Comment: You can prevent creating duplicates during an INSERT by using a WHERE NOT EXISTS() clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb510625.aspx) statement if you're on SQL SERVER 2008 or later.

this allows you to compare a source and target table, and take approriate actions when there is a match (or not) In your case you want to insert to the target table when there isn't a match by order ID.

```
MERGE tblOrderActivity AS dst
USING tblOrder AS src
ON dst.OrderID = src.OrderID AND dst.ActivityID = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (OrderID, ActivityID, ActivityDate)
VALUES (src.OrderID, 1, GETDATE());
```

Alternative approach (might be quicker than a merge statement)

```
INSERT tblOrderActivity (OrderID, ActivityID, ActivityDate)
SELECT o.OrderID, 1, GETDATE()
FROM tblOrder AS o
LEFT JOIN tblOrderActivity AS oa ON o.OrderID = oa.OrderID AND oa.ActivityID = 1
WHERE oa.OrderID IS NULL
```

Comment: should work - I did a quick test and it seemed ok. Can you end up with other entries for the same OrderID (but a different ActivityID) appearing before the `ActivityID = 1` entry? I've edited the answer just in case...

Comment: still getting "(0 row(s) affected)"

Comment: Not sure why, but I've edited the answer to add an alternative approach - which should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Will just answer the second part

"Each new order also has to have a received activity under the tblOrderActivity table with the Current Date/Time."

you will create a trigger on tblOrder table that inserts a new record into the tblOrderActivity table

```
CREATE TRIGGER tblOrder_ins
ON tblOrder
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO tblOrderActivity (OrderID, ActivityID, ActivityDate)
SELECT OrderID, 1 AS ActivityID, GETDATE()
FROM INSERTED
```

as for the first part, perhaps you should show the query you use, it will give a better understanding as to what you need.

Comment: I essentially need to create an insert statement for the first part that uses the same CustomerID and LoanNumber but a new Order ID in sequence and an OrderTypeID of 3 into tblOrder.